# Example of a simple pole

Tags: complex-analysis, definition

I was told that $\operatorname{sech} x$ has a ***simple pole***. Could someone please explain what that means? I have looked up the definition but it involves too much jargon like holomorphic, etc. Is there a simple definition and why is this true? Thanks.

Comment: For an even simpler example of a simple pole: $x=0$ is a simple pole for the function $\dfrac1{x}$.

Comment: Stanisław Łojasiewicz was a fantastic mathematician who proved very difficult inequalities about  the growth of functions on  complex analytic spaces , and yet he was very modest and always behaved like a simple Pole.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: Haha :D

Comment: Cross-posted to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16179/2451

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recall that $\operatorname{sech}(x) = \frac{1}{\cosh(x)}$. When $x \in \mathbb{R}$, hyperbolic cosine is non-negative, so $\operatorname{sech}(x)$ has no poles on the real axis.

Zeros of the hyperbolic cosine are all along the imaginary axis at $z_n =  i \frac{\pi}{2} +  i \pi n$. Consider a vicinity of such a zero:
$$\begin{align}
 \frac{1}{\cosh(z_n + \epsilon)} &= \frac{1}{\cosh(z_n) \cosh(\epsilon) + \sinh(z_n) \sinh(\epsilon)}\\ &= \frac{1}{\sinh(z_n)} \frac{1}{\sinh(\epsilon)}\\ &\sim  \frac{1}{\sinh(z_n)} \left( \frac{1}{\epsilon} + o(1) \right)
\end{align}
$$
The order of the pole is one, so it is called simple. But as you see, $\operatorname{sech}(x)$ has infinitely many simple poles.

**Added**: 
  The series [expansion](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+1%2Fsinh%28x%29) for $\frac{1}{\sinh(\epsilon)}$ follows from series expansion for $\sinh(\epsilon) \sim \epsilon + \frac{\epsilon^3}{3!} + \ldots + \frac{1}{(2n+1)!}\epsilon^{2n+1} + o(\epsilon^{2n+2})$.

Comment: Looks like you've covered it quite well. :) [This](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uOesE.png) might be of help in explaining what poles are for the OP...

Comment: Thanks, Sasha and @J.M. !

Comment: @simpleton: Because of those poles, $\mathrm{sech}$ is what would be termed as a *meromorphic* function.